# Should we always default to related Meta.SO answers to our own Meta questions?

Tags: discussion

Often, a question is asked here in Meta, and the initial answer begins with, "*this question was asked on Meta.SO, and the accepted answer was...*" (with a link to the referenced question.

I question whether we should rely on/default to the accepted answers to similar/related Meta.SO questions. Let's discuss.

Answer (score 4):

Meta.WPSE **should not** rely on/default to the accepted answer to similar/related questions on Meta.SO.

While site mechanics and conventions are consistent across all SE network sites, each site is different, meets different needs, serves different communities, deals with different types of questions, and is comprised of different users with differing expertise levels. What is appropriate/works well for the SO community *may* or *may not* work well for the WPSE community.

Currently, Meta.SO questions are linked, with the *implication* that the Meta.SO community's *accepted answer* should be our *starting point*, further implying that we would need a convincing argument to decide differently from that community. I would prefer to see references to related/similar Meta.SO questions posed as **neutral**, along the lines of, "*here's how the Meta.SO community discussed this question*", in the chance that the perspectives, issues, and arguments posed by *that* community might be constructive to *our* community's discussion.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree.